# Large number of training steps results in poor performance in transfer learning

Tags: deep-learning

I have a question. I have used transfer learning to retrain googlenet on my image classification problem. I have 80,000 images which belong to 14 categories. I set number of training steps equal to 200,000. I think the code provided by Tensorflow should have drop out implimented and it trains based on random shuffling of dataset and cross validation approach, and and I do not see any overfiting in training and classification curves, and I get high cross validation accuracy and high test accuracy but when I apply my model to new dataset then I get poor classification result. Anybodey know what is going on?Thanks!

Comment: - Are the two datasets inherently the same? Is there any possible huge difference you are simply overlooking?
 - Have you applied the same preprocessing steps to the second dataset?
 - Have you defined a proper performance metric?

Comment: Both datasets are pretty similar. I have not applied any preprocessing step as mean subtraction is performed in the code provided by tensorflow. I have not defined metric but I simply used the retrain.py script by tensorflow for transfer learning and retraining inception-v2

Comment: - "when I apply my model to new dataset then I get poor classification result" sounds like overfitting. - Have you tried to retrain the model using 60,000 of your 80,000 images, then test them on the other 20,000 ? If it works, then it might be the dataset difference issue mentioned by @MohammadRazzaghnoori ; if not, then you might need to investigate the retrain.py .